# Django manytomany through create form and view

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, has-many-through, m2m

I'm new in Django and I'm building a job board.
But I don't understand how to create a form to get related fields of a M2M through.

Here is my code:

```
#views.py
class JobDetails(generic.DetailView):

    model = Job
    template_name = 'companies/job-detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JobDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['company_detail'] = Company.objects.all()
        return context

    def apply(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ApplyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                 form.save(commit=False)

                #create job
                job = Job.objects.all.get(pk=pk)

                #create candidate
                candidate = User.objects.all.get(pk=pk)

                #assign to the through table
                candidatetojob = CandidateToJob.objects.create(job=job, candidate=candidate)


                form.save()
                candidatetojob.save()   



                 return HttpResponseRedirect('/jobs/')
         else:
                form = ApplyForm()

         return render_to_response(
             "companies/form-candtojob.html",
             {'form': form}
         )


 #forms.py
 class ApplyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CandidateToJob
        exclude = ['candidate', 'job', 'status']


 #models.py
 class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    candidate = models.ManyToManyField('Candidate', through='CandidateToJob')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

 class Candidate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='candidateprofile/%Y/%m/%d')
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username


 class CandidateToJob(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='applied_to')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, related_name='from_user')
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('0', 'New'),
        ('1', 'Not approved'),
        ('2', 'Approved'),
        ('3', 'Hired')
     )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.job.candidate.user.username
```

But in my template.html, the user candidate being loggedin apply for a job (by submit form button) I get a 405 error. I am only allowed to perform this in the admin.

Some thoughts of what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the 405 error because you do not have any POST method defined. To accept POST requests, you need a post method. You have an apply method, which you think will be POSTed, but it will never be called. Change your apply method to this:

```
def post(self, request, *args. **kwargs):
    form = ApplyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)

        #create job
        job = Job.objects.all.get(pk=pk)

        #create candidate
        candidate = User.objects.all.get(pk=pk)

        #assign to the through table
        candidatetojob = CandidateToJob.objects.create(job=job, candidate=candidate)

        form.save()
        candidatetojob.save()   

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/jobs/')

     return render_to_response(
         "companies/form-candtojob.html",
         {'form': form}
     )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you fast response. But now I'm getting for job pk "global name 'pk' is not defined". If I try job= Job.objects.get(), the error is "get() returned more than one Job". I don't know how to get the current model pk. I get only the current user pk. Can you help me? Thanks once again.

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to do. Your comments suggest you're trying to create a job, and then create a candidate, but your not creating anything. You're just retrieving from the DB. And there's no way your answer works either. `Candidate.objects.get(pk=request.user)` is saying to get the candidate with a primary key of the current users's primary key. Which makes no sense because they are separate models.

Comment: Actually it works because in the Candidate Model I have: user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True). Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. This is how I made it. Thanks.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)

        #get the job
        job = self.get_object(queryset=Job.objects.all())

        #get the user candidate
        candidate = Candidate.objects.get(pk=request.user)

        #assign to the through table
        candidatetojob = CandidateToJob.objects.create(job=job, candidate=candidate)

        candidatetojob.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect('/jobs/')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```